# Realm read on background thread

Tags: swift, realm

I did read the [documentation about threading](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#threading)

I do have 2 Models: Artist, Album and Artist has a list of Albums and albums has a linking objects to Artists.

Now I want to read all artists and all albums, the problem though is that this is blocking my UI if there are lots of objects. I iterate through artists like this:

```
let artists = realm.objects(Artist.self)
artists.forEach({ (artist: Artist) in 
   // do something with artist
   artist.albums.forEach({ (album: Album) in 
     // do something with albums
   })
})
```

This is very slow though and blocks my main thread, so I decided to put it on an async background queue. The issue is that realm cannot be accessed from a different thread. So I did this:

```
let artistsRefs = ThreadSafeReference(to: artists)
DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
  let config = Realm.Configuration()
  let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
  guard let artists = realm.resolve(artistsRefs) else {
    return
  }
  artists.forEach { (artist: Artist) in
    // do something with artists
    artist.albums.forEach{ (album: Album) in
       // do something with albums
    }
  }
}
```

I keep getting the error though, that realm has been accessed from the wrong thread.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'
```

Any idea what's wrong and how I can read any object on a different queue using realm? I just want to read so there is no chance of a dirty write and no chance of a dirty read.

Thanks

Comment: what if you remove the `linking objects` and use a `RealmList<Artist>` in your `Album` ? You'll have to add artists to the albums when you set your data. Instead of using threads

Comment: Well just from the point of modelling it needs to be a many to many relationship (in most cases it is a one to many, but with features etc.)

Comment: It can be a many to many without linking objects : https://gist.github.com/mgohin/f0c6a149d95c36580aa2d2163c226c2f
I removed all linking objects and replaced with RealmList I have to manually managed to get better performances

Comment: The ThreadSafeReference and .resolve may not be needed here. That's for when you need to pass thread-confined instances. That doesn't seem to be the case here - you are loading in the data, processing it, and that all could just happen on the same thread. Remember that as long as you specify the same configuration, all Realm instances will map to the same file on disk. Check out the example in  [Using Realm Across Threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads). The example is a write but you could do the same thing with a read on a background thread.

Comment: @JanoschHübner did you find a solution? I have almost the exact same problem.